# Think Python 4.1: Why does printing bob give me an object rather than an instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

All other answers on stackoverflow about instances vs. objects refer to classes, which the book hasn't covered yet.
This is the code:

```
world= TurtleWorld()
bob= Turtle()
print bob
wait_for_user()
```

and this is the result:

It shows the turtle in a box, and prints

```
<swampy.TurtleWorld.Turtle object at 0x03C3D730>
```

The book says it should say 'instance', not object. What's the difference, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about writing questions that will attract quality answers.

Comment: An instance of a class is called an object.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Python old-style classes indeed use `instance` in the representation.

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance; an instance is a *kind* of Python object. If you didn't have an instance, you'd see something different:

```
<class 'swampy.TurtleWorld.Turtle'>
```

Now, in Python 2 using old-style classes, it would indeed have said `instance`; I can create such an object by *not* inheriting from `object`:

```
>>> class Turtle: pass
...
>>> Turtle()
<__main__.Turtle instance at 0x10199fe18>
```

However, the current [swampy release](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/) uses *new-style classes*; where the class inherits from `object`:

```
>>> from swampy.TurtleWorld import Turtle
>>> Turtle.__mro__
(<class 'swampy.TurtleWorld.Turtle'>, <class 'swampy.World.Animal'>, <type 'object'>)
```

New-style classes do things a little different, and some things have been renamed and unified. I think you are using the first edition of Think Python, based on code not using new-style classes.

You can probably complete your tutorial with only minor cosmetic changes like these showing up.

However, you may want to find a newer, more recent book; Think Python has a 2nd edition using Python 3, for example.